# Why DIGITS showing this error: ERROR: Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (77 vs. 0) an illegal memory access was encountered

Tags: caffe, nvidia-digits

DIGITS was working very well on my device, however, it is giving an error

```
ERROR: Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (77 vs. 0) an illegal memory access was encountered
```

I do not know how to tackle this.Thanks

Comment: Add information about your cuda and cudnn configuration. This PR https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/4169 seems to say you have problem with cuda installation. You might try decreasing batch size.

Comment: Also, check your Caffe version. DIGITS recommends using the latest version of NVIDIA/Caffe.